# How to change webflow variable on key pressed?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, spring-webflow

I have flowScope variable in Spring WebFlow. I want to change it by pressing particular key from keyboard. So i need some ability to change it. I think about rich:hotkey, but what can be the function?

```
<rich:hotKey key="esc"  onkeyup="???" />
```

May be some other ideas?
I need call to the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a4j:jsFunction` is what you want, you can use it like this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="myFunction" actionListener="#{bean.changeFlow}" /> 

<rich:hotKey key="esc" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: Thx. By the way, after using it the whole page gets refreshed, but why? I set "render" attribute of a4j:jsFunction to render what i need. Also, "oncomplete" doesn't works for the same reason I guess

Comment: Add `execute="@this"` to the jsFunction. I'm not sure what's the default value but it is probably executing other components on the page.

Comment: All is fine. Was project specific issue.